# Is there a coordinate-independent representation for the Lienard-Wiechert potentials?

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-geometry

Treat particle trajectories as embedded submanifolds in the pseudo-Euclidean space, and treat the four-dimensional potential as a 1-form.Is there a statement for the Lienard-Wiechert potentials that does not mention coordinate components?

Comment: Write the field equation for the potential 1-form and solve it.

Comment: The L-W potential is usually written in terms of vectors, not coordinates.